# What happens if a voltage is applied to an output MCU pin?

Tags: microcontroller

As in the question suppose that we have an I/O pin configured as an output.
What could happen to the pin if we apply a 5 volt to it while it is on High state and while on low state?
If you need technical specifications ,i am using an atmega 328 p.

Comment: What is the supply voltage, just before and during the time of contact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the MCU is outputting a different voltage from the voltage on the pin a large current will flow (50-100mA probably).  If left to persist this could damage the MCU.

You should design your hardware/software to avoid this situation.

If you can't avoid it you can put a series resistor to limit the current to a safe value - the max value for the ATMEGA328 is 40mA I believe.  This would imply a series resistor >125 ohm.

Comment: 40mA is the Absolute Maximum ratings which really should not be run at - the IC isn't characterised above 20mA per pin @5V (10mA @3V) meaning really you shouldn't have a series resistance > 250 Ohm for protection. Also depending on the number of IO pins this is happening on, there are limitations on the supply pins as well.

Comment: Is there a safe solution to protect the MCU from such scenarios?

Comment: @Med.ali Yes, the solution is to avoid such scenarios.

Comment: @Tom.  Surely you meant "really you shouldn't have a series resistance < 250 Ohm". I agree with you.  But the concept is to put a limiting resistor if you cannot avoid an output conflict - By design I've have always managed to avoid any such situation.

Comment: @KevinWhite yes, sorry that was supposed to say "*Should* have a series resistance > 250 Ohm", not shouldn't. And yes it is far better to design your circuit such that two outputs cannot drive the same line **unless** they are either both open drain, or both open collector (no mix and match!)

Comment: @TomCarpenter What's the problem with mixing open drain and open collector (assuming both the same 'polarity')?

Comment: You should never write stuff when tired... I think I was thinking along the lines of whatever the opposite of open drain is (the one which is just a transistor which pulls to VDD, instead of GND) and then used the wrong name. I'll go away now, possibly go sleep!